# Need to extract date from a text file of strings in R

Tags: r

I have a text file. It contains lots of text in following format:

- text
- text
- Date in format of 12 December 2016
- text
- text

How do I extract only the date in such a case given that there is no other date in the text section of the file? Need a R program for it.

Comment: You can check out lubridate!

Answer (score 1):

This would do the trick. You would get the the dates parsed while the rest would become NA objects which you can filter out.

```
text=c('a','b','12 December 2016','10 December 2015')

strptime(text,format='%d %B %Y')
```

Comment: 'strptime' is in base. No need for 'library(lubridate)'

Comment: @cory Thanks removed the library

Answer (score 0):

I've called your data set demo_set for practical purposes.
You start by reading in your data set:
`demo_set=readLines(con <- file("yourFile.txt") #read in file.`

You can use other ways of reading in your data set.
Then you use regex to find lines with month names.

```
demo_set[grep(pattern = paste(month.name,collapse = "|"),demo_set)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text doesn't starts with number you can use the below code

```
abc<- subset(abc, grepl("^[0-9]",name))
```

where `abc` is your dataframe and `name` is your column in your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an if statement to check if there are any values within a column such as Date, and print them to screen like so;

```
if(!is.na(data$date)) {
  print(data$date)
}
```

This will print all the records where there is a value in Date but if you would rather just a sample, use;

```
print(data$date[1:10])
```